# How to use a callback in specific thread in order to wait for it in the main thread?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

First question here, I will do my best.

I have a Data class that retrieve a data object with firestore at the creation.
I have done some code to the setters with coroutines. I am not sure of my solution but it is working. However, for the getters, I am struggling to wait the initialisation.

In the initialisation, I have a callback to retrieve the data. The issue that the callback is always called from the main thread, event if I use it in a coroutine in another thread. I check this with:

```
Log.d("THREAD", "Execution thread1: "+Thread.currentThread().name)
```

For the setter I use a coroutine in useTask to not block the main thread. And a mutex to block this coroutine until the initialisation in the init is done. Not sure about waitInitialisationSuspend but it is working.

But for the getter, I just want to block the main thread (even if it is bad design, it is a first solution) until the initialisation is done, and resume the getter to retrieve the value.
But I am not enable to block the main thread without also blocking the callback in the initialisation because there are in the same thread.

I have read many documentation about coroutine, scope, runBlocking, thread etc. but everything gets mixed up in my head.

```
class Story(val id: String) :  BaseObservable() {

    private val storyRef = StoryHelper.getStoryRef(id)!!
    private var isInitialized = false
    private val initMutex = Mutex(true)

    @get:Bindable
    var dbStory: DbStory? = null

    init {
         storyRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                dbStory = snapshot.toObject(DbStory::class.java)!!
                if (!isInitialized) {
                    initMutex.unlock()
                    isInitialized = true
                }
                notifyPropertyChanged(BR.dbStory)
            }
        }
    }

    fun interface StoryListener {
        fun onEvent()
    }

    private fun useTask(function: (task: Task) -> Unit): Task {
        val task = Task()
        GlobalScope.launch {
            waitInitialisationSuspend()
            function(task)
        }
        return task
    }

    private suspend fun waitInitialisationSuspend()
    {
        initMutex.withLock {
            // no op wait for unlock mutex
        }
    }

    fun typicalSetFunction(value: String) : Task {
        return useTask { task ->
            storyRef.update("fieldName", value).addOnSuccessListener {
                task.doEvent()
            }
        }
    }

    fun typicalGetFunction(): String
    {
        var result = ""

        // want something to wait the callback in the init.

        return result
    }
}
```

RunBlocking seems to block the main tread, so I can not use it if the callback still use the main thread.
It is the same problem if I use a while loop in main thread.

#1

```
runBlocking {
     initMutex.withLock {
         result = dbStory!!.value
     }
}
```

#2

```
while (!isInitialized){
}
result = dbStory!!.value
```

#3
Because maybe the callback in the init is in the main thread also. I have tried to launch this initialisation in a coroutines with a IO dispatcher but without success. The coroutine is well in a different thread but the callback still called in the main thread.

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
```

```
scope.launch() {
            reference.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
```

In the getter, I have to work with the main thread. The solution is maybe to put the callback execution in another thread but I do not know how to do this. And maybe there is a better solution.

Another solution will be te be able to wait the callback in the main thread without blocking the callback but I have no solution for this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have loocked for many solutions and the conclusion is, don't do it.

This design is worse than I thougt. Android does not want you to block the main thread even for a short time. Blocking the main thread is blocking all UI and synchronisation mecanism, it is really bad solution.

Even using another thread for the callback (that you can do with an Executor) is, I think, a bad idea here. The good way to wait the end of the task in the callback is to retrieve the task and use:

```
Tasks.await(initTask)
```

But it is not allowed in the main thread. Android prevent you to do bad design here.

We should deal with the asynchronous way to manage firebase data base, it is the best way to do that.
I can still use my cache on the data. Here I was waiting to display a dialog with a text I retrieve in firebase. So, I can just display the dialog asynchronously when the text data is retrieved. If the cache is available, it will use it.

Keep also in mind that firebase seems to have some API to use a cache.